# How to express this action: "I am hungry and dredge / scoop the little left-over food in the pot as much as possible"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This is the context, you are so hungry & you found a pot with very little food sticking on the bottom of the pot. You then scoop the little left-over food in the pot as much as possible to eat.

what word should I use?

I am hungry and **dredge / scoop the little left-over food** in the pot as much as possible with a spoon.

Comment: You scrape out as much food as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dredge has a rather nasty connotation and wouldn't be used for food.
Scoop may be right here, but I like the other user's suggestion of scrape.
My recommendation would be to rephrase the sentence like this:

> I am hungry so I scrape as much of the left-over food out of the pot as possible.

This is easier to understand, as I feel that you were trying to fit too many thoughts into one clause. I would recommend removing the word 'little' as it feels redundant. But if you wanted to emphasize the little amount of food int the pot, I would add it as an extra sentence.

> I am hungry so I scrape as much of the left-over food out of the pot as possible. There was not very much left.

Comment: But I am using a spoon to do it, can "scrape"  be used with a spoon?

Comment: Yes, you can 'scrape' a pot with a spoon.